# hibernate create criteria function print question mark on the console

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I have write hibernate createcriteria function in my project like this

```
Hibernatesession.createCriteria(Salesman.class).add(Restrictions.ilike("email", email)).list();
```

The email here is a variable and and i got this correctly in my dao page.
But the query here got in the console is

```
select this_.id as id28_0_, this_.city_id as city2_28_0_, this_.state_id as state3_28_0_, this_.firstname as firstname28_0_, this_.lastname as lastname28_0_, this_.address as address28_0_, this_.zip as zip28_0_, this_.phone as phone28_0_, this_.suit as suit28_0_, this_.username as username28_0_, this_.password as password28_0_, this_.email as email28_0_, this_.status as status28_0_, this_.created_at as created14_28_0_ from test_mydrdirect.salesman this_ where lower(this_.email) like ?
```

instaed of it should print in the console like this

```
select this_.id as id28_0_, this_.city_id as city2_28_0_, this_.state_id as state3_28_0_, this_.firstname as firstname28_0_, this_.lastname as lastname28_0_, this_.address as address28_0_, this_.zip as zip28_0_, this_.phone as phone28_0_, this_.suit as suit28_0_, this_.username as username28_0_, this_.password as password28_0_, this_.email as email28_0_, this_.status as status28_0_, this_.created_at as created14_28_0_ from test_mydrdirect.salesman this_ where lower(this_.email) like 'test@gmail.com'
```

instead of `test@gmail.com` hibernate print just a '?' in the console. Anybody know why is this print like this.

Comment: that's because hibernate use prepared statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These queries are treated as prepared statement and the parameters are bind on to the values just when the queries getting executed. But, you can still log them as below.

If you want detailed logging of hibernate queries you need to use the below logging mechanism as explained in an article [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-log4j-in-hibernate-project/).

Add the below in your **log4.properties**  file,

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\mkyongapp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO

# Log all JDBC parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL
```

Here is another [example](http://ideoplex.com/id/386/controlling-hibernate-output-with-log4j) of the same.